# Android: Unable to Scroll down a spinner

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner, android-theme, android-styles

In here I'm using a 'Spinner' with 'android:theme' for change the color of underline and drop down arrow of the spinner. And also 'style' for get base style for the spinner and 'android:popupBackground' for spinner popup background color. Finally I'm using 'spinner_item.xml' for change the text color of the spinner. After doing all of the above the spinner doesn't scroll up or down. Below is my code.

**@styles/styles.xml**

```
<style name="SpinnerStyle">
   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
</style>
```

**activity.xml**

```
<Spinner
            android:id="@+id/news_source_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
            android:theme="@style/SpinnerStyle"
            android:popupBackground="#80000000"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:focusable="true"/>
```

**@layout/spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@BindView(R.id.news_source_spinner)
        Spinner newsSourceSpinner;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.spinner_item, itemList);
    newsSourceSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally I solved my issue with following code to set fixed height for the spinner popup.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    try {
        Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        popup.setAccessible(true);

        // Get private mPopup member variable and try cast to ListPopupWindow
        android.widget.ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (android.widget.ListPopupWindow) popup.get(spinner);

        // Set popupWindow height to 500px
        popupWindow.setHeight(500);
    }
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // silently fail...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dude, setting a fixed height worked for me too. Weird one as it worked fine on some Androids and not others